# How change the querystring for a submited form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form with many dropdownlist and i want to exclude the none selected ones from appearing in the querystring when the form is submitted.
So can i use some module or filter to change this behavior.

Ex:
When i search for test the url will be
/someaction?q=test&select1=&select2=
The required url is :
/someaction?q=test

```
<form action="/search" action="Get">
        <label>Search term <input name="q"></label>

<select id="select1" name="select1">
<option value="1">option 1</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" name="select2">
<option value="1">option 1</option>
</select>


        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using GET method for form action, you can handle submit event to prevent normal submit and strip out empty values using `replace()` function with regex, then use `location.href` to redirect into target URL:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var queryString = $(this).serialize().replace(/&?[\w\-\d_]+=&|&?[\w\-\d_]+=$/gi, "");
    url = this.getAttribute('action') + (queryString.length > 0 ? "?" + queryString : "");

    // returns URL /search?q=something when both select elements are empty 
    location.href = url;
});
```

Or disable the `select` elements without values on-the-fly using `attr()` or `prop()` to prevent them used in query string, using normal form submit event:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $('select').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled'); // or prop('disabled', true)
    });
});
```

Comment: I have used the second method and it works great. Thank you